# Are Theme-specific Drawables considered 'internal'?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme

In Android Studio 2.2.2 'Project' view I select:
*External Libraries > Android API 27 Platform > res > drawable*.

Almost side-to-side, I see the following 2 State List Drawables:
**btn_default**.xml
**btn_default_holo_light**.xml

To normalize my Buttons after temporary highlighting, I have been successfully issuing the following command to apply the (Android default theme) background.

```
btn.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(CTX.gc(),android.R.drawable.btn_default));
```

I now wish to apply the background specific to my Theme ('android:Theme.Holo.Light')  but compiler rejects both the following commands with 'Cannot resolve symbol'.

```
btn.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(CTX.gc(),android.R.drawable.btn_default_holo_light));
btn.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(CTX.gc(),android.R.drawable.btn_default_holo_light, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light));
```

But in fact, they ARE resolve-able because 'right-click > go to > declaration' successfully invokes the editor against the desired Drawable.

The crux of the matter is that when manually typing the command, **btn_default** is offered in the type-ahead choices whereas **btn_default_holo_light** isn't. So apparently the theme-specific entities are considered internal and therefore not included in [android.R.drawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.drawable).

Is there perhaps an R.drawable for themes, or indeed any method of referencing these Drawables?